# JS prompt, and functions syntax in loop parameters

Tags: javascript, function, loops, while-loop

I am embarrassed to post my attempt at the very first practice exercise in You Don't Know JavaScript: Up and Going." However, I am hoping someone can tell me what (surely multiple things) I am doing wrong here. I am stuck at work so I using the AWS Cloud9 JS compiler. The current error I keep getting is something about each of my prompts. It reads "ReferenceError: prompt is not defined." Am I using the proper syntax for the while loop?

Also, I feel like StackOverflow is meant for more specific and higher level questions. Where does one go with the basic dumb beginner questions?

```
// Declare the prices of the various phones& accessories in stock and tax 
rate.
const TAX_RATE = 0.09;
const IPHONE = 500;
const GALAXY = 469;
const WINDOZE_PHONE = 369;
const EL_CHEAPO = 69;
const SCREEN_PROTECTOR = 10;
const DONGLE = 12;
const CASE = 20;
const CAR_CHARGER = 20;

//initialize global variables.
var accessories =0;
var chosenPhone;

//create a function we can call each time we need to check which phone is 
selected.
function whichPhone(phonePrompt){
var phonePrompt = prompt("Enter 1, 2, 3, or 4 for an iPhone, Samsung 
Galaxy," + "Windows Phone, or Cheap Phone respectively.");

switch (phonePrompt){
        case (1):
            chosenPhone = IPHONE;
        case (2):
            chosenPhone = GALAXY;
        case (3):
            chosenPhone = WINDOZE_PHONE;
        case (4):
            chosenPhone = EL_CHEAPO;
            break;
        default:
            alert("You gotta enter a number 1 through 4. If not, ya broke it");
        }
    }

//create a function to add the price for each accessory added to the bill
function upsell(confirmUpsell){
    var confirmUpsell = confirm("Would you like to buy any acessories today?");

    if (confirmUpsell === true){
        var accessoryPrompt1 = confirm("Would you like a fancy screen protector?");
            if (accessoryPrompt1 === true){
                accessories += SCREEN_PROTECTOR;
            }
        var accessoryPrompt2 = confirm("Would you like a dongle?");
            if (accessoryPrompt2 === true){
                    accessories += DONGLE;
                }
        var accessoryPrompt3 = confirm("Would you like a protective case?");
            if (accessoryPrompt3 === true){
                accessories += CASE;
            }
        var accessoryPrompt4 = confirm("Would you like a car charger?");
            if (accessoryPrompt4 === true){
                accessories += CAR_CHARGER;
            }
    else { accessories = 0;
        }
    }
}

/*Endlessly buy phones and opt to buy accessories until your bank acocunt no
longer suffices for a phone. Be sure to include an option for being too broke
to buy any phone to begin with.
Determine which phone the user wants and see if they can afford it.
Then check if they can afford accessories.*/

var bankBalance = prompt("Enter your current bank balance.");

whichPhone();

    while (whichPhone.chosenPhone < bankBalance){
        upsell();
        var salePrice = ((chosenPhone + accessories) * TAX_RATE) + (chosenPhone + accessories);
        bankBalance -= salePrice;
        console.log("You have $" + bankBalance + "remaining.");
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried `window.prompt`? Maybe you need to defined globals somehow?

Comment: `prompt` is being overwritten somewhere.

Comment: You'll get this error in node.js too. `prompt` is a browser function. If you want it on the command line you'll need to install something like: https://docs.nodejitsu.com/articles/command-line/how-to-prompt-for-command-line-input/